# How to add Info.plist file to Xcode for admob, error Multiple commands produce after I added

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

> Multiple commands produce '/Users/gan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xx-fpgsryfzwqufgxcplcdfxrycppjh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xx.app/Info.plist'

> Target 'xx' (project 'xx') has copy command from '/Users/gan/Downloads/xx/Info.plist' to '/Users/gan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/x-xfpgsryfzwqufgxcplcdfxrycppjh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xx.app/Info.plist'
> Target 'xx' (project 'xx') has process command with output '/Users/gan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xx-fpgsryfzwqufgxcplcdfxrycppjh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xx.app/Info.plist'

[image]

The file content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchScreen</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After I removed the Info.plist in the build rule settings, it has this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set a valid application ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        return true
    }
}


@main
struct CatAPIProjectApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76700965/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by just remove this file, there was an original Info.plist in the project, we can't see the file, just edit in the "Info" configuration, press "+" to add.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Multiple commands produce ... info.plist` means there are duplicate `info.plist` files in the target. So there are two main reason and solutions for this:

1. Uncheck `add to target` for one of them if they are using a identical `info.plist`
2. If don't identical, Merge them into a one single file.

**Note that** in the newer Xcode projects, the file behind the `info.plist` is hidden and you need to change the configuration of it by selecting the project file -> selecting the target -> and the `Info` section:

[image: Implicit]

You can also fallback to using a file by adding it to the project and changing the default settings for the path to it and the **Generate Info.plist File** to `NO`

[image: Explicit]